# Why is my C#/MySQL connection timeout setting being ignored?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I have a long running query that takes about 1 minute to complete from a MySQL normal client.

However when I run it in my C# application I appear to get the standard MySQL connection timeout error after 30 seconds despite setting it to 240 seconds in the connection string.

Is there another Timeout setting I can't find?

**Error message**

Exception: "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

InnerException: "Reading from the stream has failed."

InnerException: "Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

**Code**

```
public static string GetMySQLconnectionString()
{
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();

    conn_string.Server             = "127.0.0.1";
    conn_string.Port               = 4302;
    conn_string.UserID             = "root";
    conn_string.Password           = "";
    conn_string.Database           = "my_database";
    conn_string.CharacterSet       = "utf8";
    conn_string.SslMode            = MySqlSslMode.None;
    conn_string.ConnectionTimeout  = 240;

    return conn_string.ToString();
}

internal static string getTotalSitesThatStillNeedDNSChecking()
{
    try
    {
        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConnUpdate = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(GetMySQLconnectionString()))
        {
            dbConnUpdate.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = dbConnUpdate.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) as counter FROM all_domains WHERE last_dns_check IS NULL";
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (!reader.HasRows) return "0";

            reader.Read();

            return (string)reader["counter"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Logger.AddError("error - ", ex, "grand-total-stat-calculator"); return "0"; }
}
```

Comment: You are having a connection failure not a timeout from the actual query.   Instead of using 127.0.0.1 use the IP of the computer or computer name.  Not all machines are configured for loopback IP address 127.0.0.1.  Are you failing on the OPEN or the SELECT?

Comment: Thanks but I can see the SQL query running but it just throws that error after 30 seconds and all other queries work fine just not this long running one

Comment: The command has a default timeout of 30 seconds.  Change the command timeout.

Comment: Try change local ip to "localhost"

Comment: `ConnectionTimeout` sets the timeout just for the initial connection, not for any subsequent command executed on that connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to set the CommandTimeout like so

```
    try
    {
        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection dbConnUpdate = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(GetMySQLconnectionString()))
        {
            dbConnUpdate.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = dbConnUpdate.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandTimeout = 240;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) as counter FROM all_domains WHERE last_dns_check IS NULL";
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (!reader.HasRows) return "0";

            reader.Read();

            return (string)reader["counter"].ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Logger.AddError("error - ", ex, "grand-total-stat-calculator"); return "0"; }
```

Comment: You can also set `DefaultCommandTimeout` in your connection string, to set that automatically for all commands.